# Geo coder not saving any information in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

Ive installed geocoder gem but when i type the address in the form it doesnt save any params in the table, its just an empty object. is there something im missing?

The location model:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :postcode, :longitude, :latitude
geocoded_by :postcode
after_validation :geocode, :if => :postcode_changed?

end
```

The location controller:

```
    def create
      @location = Location.new(location_params)
       if @location.save
         redirect_to message_path(current_user.id)
         flash[:success] = "Success"
       else
         redirect_to root_path
         flash[:danger] = "failed"
       end
    end

    private

    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:postcode, :user_id)
    end
```

Here is the form:

```
    <%= form_for @location, :url => locations_path do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label "postcode" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :postcode %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
      </p>
      <p><%= f.submit %></p>
    <% end %>
```

And here is my schema:

```
      create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "postcode"
        t.float "longitude"
        t.float "latitude"
        t.bigint "user_id"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
        t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_locations_on_user_id"
      end
```

So the idea is that a user would enter his postcode in the form on his profile page his location would show for all the other users to see.

I may not have grasped the concept of it so any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Oh and here is the table entry after save:

```
irb(main):011:0> Location.last
Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Location id: 10, postcode: nil, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, 
user_id: 9, created_at: "2017-10-17 09:40:43", updated_at: "2017-10-17 09:40:43">
```

Comment: You can't geocode with just a postcode - how is the lookup supposed to know what country the code is for? You need an address string like "Paris, France" or "34-35 New Bond St, Mayfair, London W1A 2AA, Great Britain"

Comment: Note that this differs depending on which street adress service you are using so check the docs for the particular service. https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#street-address-services

Comment: thanks for the heads up, even so its still not working

Comment: Break the problem down. Find out on the model level first if the geocoder callback is being called by creating a location with an address and see if there the lat/lng is being set. I would do this with a unit test.

Comment: Then I would try to figure out if the `postcode` param is being passed properly through the form/controller. I can't spot any issues but you are getting `postcode: nil`.

Comment: Why is your postcode itself is nil? Did u entered nothing?

Comment: i am entering an address all the params arrive in the controller but after save it it all disappears...

Comment: I resolved it by removing the attr_accessor, thanks for the help